# How to draw an object that's tilted in two perspective system

Tags: drawing, perspective

Suppose I have a two perspective system but I want to draw an object that's not aligned with the two perspectives. Like, maybe it's rotated somehow... something like this:

(sorry for the terrible drawing, I just got myself a drawing pad, still getting used to it)

So my question is, how do I create variety in my drawing? I can't have all objects be exactly aligned, perpendicular to each other right?

[image]

Comment: If you know the angle difference then you can construct a different set of wanishinpoints

Comment: ok thanks. how is that called? should be fairly commonly used because in drawing things are not all parallel and perpendicular to each other.

Comment: It reallt depends on wether you only use a protractor and ruler. If on a computer it may just be easier to do a perpective divide on a matrix transform.

Comment: No. Suppose I only use a protractor and a ruler

Comment: The simplest solution is to ignore any "two point perspective" approach and simply draw what you want. Artists, for centuries, drew perspective without any grid or system. And much of the paintings from The Masters, while containing visual perspective, will fail miserably if you try and apply some grid system to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object has its own perspective. Simply draw two more vanishing points consistent with your drawing.

Every line has its own perspective. Every square face (parallelogram) has its own perspective.

It is just that normally a series of objects share the same vanishing points, some city blocks, a table with the wall, etc. But you can simply rotate a chair to offset the vanishing point.

Take a look at some other questions:
[At what point does 1 point perspective become 2 point perspective?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117014/at-what-point-does-1-point-perspective-become-2-point-perspective)